# how to set the server status code for http response?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have this angular client code:

```
        $http.put('api/Voices/updateVoice', {voice : voice, isAddMode : isAddMode}).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                lastUpdateStatus = response.data;
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                var responseStr = JSON.stringify(response)
                console.log("server error: "+responseStr);
                deferred.reject(response.data);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
```

and this java server code:
which returns a jax-rs response object.

```
    @Path("/foo")
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public Response updateVoice(VoiceUpdateRequest voiceUpdateRequest) throws Exception {

        try {
            voicesInDb = rulesUiRepository.getUiVoices();

            logger.info("ACTION-LOG: " + (voiceUpdateRequest.isAddMode ? "Add" : "Edit") + " voice: " + voiceUpdateRequest.voice);
            logger.info("ACTION-LOG: DB state: " + voicesInDb);

            boolean isAddMode = voiceUpdateRequest.isAddMode;
            VoiceUi voiceUi = voiceUpdateRequest.voice;

//        validateVoiceUi(voiceUi);

            if (!isAddMode) { //edit mode
                voicesInDb.remove(voiceUi);
            } else {
                voiceUi.orderIndex = voicesInDb.nextAvailableVoiceId;
                voicesInDb.nextAvailableVoiceId++;
            }

            voicesInDb.insert(voiceUi);

            OperationType operationType = isAddMode ? OperationType.ADD : OperationType.EDIT;
            updateDbAndCofman(operationType, voiceUi.id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            String error = "error: "+ ExceptionUtils.getMessage(ex)+"---->---> trace: "+ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);
            logger.error("update voice filed. "+error);

            return Response.status(500).entity(error).build();
        }

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

I have tried to rewrite it so it to use my custom model `response`

How can i set response status code so the client will know which callback to call?

```
    @Path("/foo")
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public VoicesOperationResult updateVoice(VoiceUpdateRequest voiceUpdateRequest) throws Exception {

        VoicesOperationResult voicesOperationResult = new VoicesOperationResult();

        try {
...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

               voicesOperationResult.status = 500;
            voicesOperationResult.message = ExceptionUtils.getMessage(ex);
            voicesOperationResult.trace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);

            return voicesOperationResult;
        }

        voicesOperationResult.status = 200;
        return voicesOperationResult;
    }
```

Comment: my bad. fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the ServletResponse by adding an annotated parameter. Then you can set the HTTP return code yourself:

```
public VoicesOperationResult updateVoice(VoiceUpdateRequest voiceUpdateRequest, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
  [...]
  response.setStatus(500);
}
```

jaxrs might overwrite this though. Let me know if it works.